# Please why is there a circular import error

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am working on a django project, but it returns the included urlconf "myapp.urls"does not appear to have any patterns in it.

I tried checking my views to ensure I imported everything correctly

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from .views import home
from accounts.views import login_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',home),
    path('accounts/login/', login_view),
]
```

I expect the site to run and redirect me to the login page
This is my views in the same directory with the urls.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def home(request):
    return render(request,"home.html")
```

This is the `views.py` for the accounts.

```py
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect

from django.contrib.auth import(
    authenticate,
    get_user_model,
    login,
    logout
)

from .forms import UserLoginForm, UserRegisterForm

def login_view(request):
    next = request.GET.get('next')
    form = UserLoginForm()
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)
        login(request,user)
        if next:
            return redirect(next)
        return redirect("/")

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, "login.html",context)
```

Comment: does your `views.py` import by any chance import the `.urls`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem No it doesn't

Comment: Which version of `django` and can you add the includes in the views file?

Comment: @Tim I am using django 2.2

Comment: What are your imports in `forms.py`?

Comment: @ 00 ```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import(
    authenticate,
    get_user_model
)
```

Comment: Which `urls.py` have you shown? Is it the one in the same directory as `settings.py`, and is `ROOT_URLCONF` pointing to it? If you include the full traceback it might show what the problem is.

Comment: @Alasdair I've shown the only ```urls.py``` I have, yes it is the same in the ```settings.py```

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with the code you posted. If you're able to link to a public repository then somebody might be able to spot the problem.

Comment: @Alasdair   https://github.com/jbrit/djusers.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your project on Django 2.2, I don't see a circular import. Instead I see the error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is prohibited; form UserRegisterForm needs updating.
```

Looking at your form, you haven't set fields, you have `model = Userfields = [...]` instead.

```
class UserRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    class Meta:
        model = Userfields = [
            'username',
            'email',
            'password',
            "c_password"
        ]
```

Change it so that you set `fields`. You can remove `'password'` and `'c_password'` since you define these on your form separately.

```
class UserRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    class Meta:
        fields = [
            'username',
            'email',
        ]
```